# VirtualTreeView add roots with Threads

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy, virtualtreeview, indy-9

I would like to add roots to a VirtualTreeView http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview with a thread like this:

```
function AddRoot ( p : TForm1 ) : Integer; stdcall;
begin
 p.VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(NIL);
end;    

var
 Dummy : DWORD;
 i     : Integer;
begin
 for i := 0 to 2000 do begin
  CloseHandle(CreateThread(NIL,0, @ADDROOT, Self,0, Dummy));
 end;
end;
```

The reason for this is that I want to add all connections from my INDY Server to the TreeView. Indy's onexecute/onconnect get's called as a thread. So if 3+ connections come in at the same time the app crashes due to the TreeView. Same is if a client gets disconnected and I want to delete the Node.

I am using Delphi7 and Indy9

Any Idea how to fix that?

EDIT:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin 
 VirtualStringTree1.DeleteNode(PVirtualNode(Athread.Data)); // For Disconnection(s)
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
 Athread.Data := TObject(VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(NIL)); // For Connection(s);
end;
```

It works fine with ListView (at least better).

EDIT: Here is my full code:

Server:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
 Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
 Dialogs, ComCtrls, IDSync, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPServer,
 VirtualTrees;

type
 TForm1 = class(TForm)
 IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
 VirtualStringTree1: TVirtualStringTree;
 procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
 procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
 procedure IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
private
 { Private declarations }
public
 { Public declarations }
end;

type
 TAddRemoveNodeSync = class(TIdSync)
protected
 procedure DoSynchronize; override;
public
 Node   : PVirtualNode;
 Adding : Boolean;
end;

var
 Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TAddRemoveNodeSync.DoSynchronize;
begin
 if Adding then
  Node := Form1.VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(nil)
 else
  Form1.VirtualStringTree1.DeleteNode(Node);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 IDTCPServer1.DefaultPort := 8080;
 IDTCPServer1.Active      := TRUE;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
 with TAddRemoveNodeSync.Create do
  try
   Adding := True;
   Synchronize;
   AThread.Data := TObject(Node);
  finally
   Free;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
 with TAddRemoveNodeSync.Create do
  try
   Adding := False;
   Node := PVirtualNode(AThread.Data);
   Synchronize;
  finally
   Free;
   AThread.Data := nil;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Client (Stresser):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
 SysUtils,
 Windows,
 Winsock;

Const
 // Connection Vars
 Port         = 8080;
 Host         = '127.0.0.1';
 StressDelay  = 1; // Miliseconds!

var 
 WSA          : TWSADATA;
 MainSocket   : TSocket;
 Addr         : TSockAddrIn;

begin
 if WSAStartup($0202, WSA) <> 0 then exit;
 Addr.sin_family      := AF_INET;
 Addr.sin_port        := htons(Port);
 Addr.sin_addr.S_addr := INET_ADDR(Host);
 while true do begin
  MainSocket           := Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  Connect(MainSocket, Addr, SizeOf(Addr));
  CloseSocket(MainSocket); // Disconnect!
  sleep (StressDelay); 
 end;
end.
```

Comment: Why don't you run all the UI code on the main thread?

Comment: Cause Indy calls OnConnect in a thread. Not in the main Thread.

Comment: So what? Run the UI code in the main thread. Use some message passing mechanism to achieve that.

Comment: Add your connection information into a thread-safe queue. From your main thread it's very easy to dequeue the information into a virtual treeview.

Comment: How am I supposed to that? :/ Any Ideas?

Comment: Do not call the virtual string tree directly from the Disconnect/Connect events. Create an object with the necessary structure and add it into the queue. In a timer event from your main thread, you can check if the queue is populated and dequeue the object. See [thread-safe-queue](http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/showthread.php?4961-freepascal-Delphi-thread-safe-queue) for an example of such a queue.

Comment: @LU Posting messages is far better than polling which is usually a very bad idea

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, posting messages is also a good alternative. It's sometimes better to use a queue when there is risk of flooding then windows message queue.

Comment: @LU lots of ways to do it but polling is usually bad

Comment: I don't understand your update. Do you not believe that you must run your UI code in the main thread?

Comment: The update is just to show you why I need to synchronize. Thank you for all your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you commented, `TIdTCPServer` is a multithreaded component.  You must synchronize with the main thread in order to access the UI safely from the `TIdTCPServer` events.  You can use Indy's own `TIdSync` (synchronous) or `TIdNotify` (asynchronous) class for that purpose, eg:

```
type
  TAddRemoveNodeSync = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  public
    Node: PVirtualNode; 
    Adding: Boolean;
  end;

procedure TAddRemoveNodeSync.DoSynchronize;
begin
  if Adding then
    Node := Form1.VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(nil)
  else
    Form1.VirtualStringTree1.DeleteNode(Node);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread); 
begin 
  with TAddRemoveNodeSync.Create do
  try
    Adding := True;
    Synchronize;
    AThread.Data := TObject(Node);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end; 

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread); 
begin 
  with TAddRemoveNodeSync.Create do
  try
    Adding := False;
    Node := PVirtualNode(AThread.Data);
    Synchronize;
  finally
    Free;
    AThread.Data := nil;
  end;
end;
```

**Update:** Based on new info, I would do something more like this instead:

```
type
  TAddRemoveClientNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  protected
    fAdding: Boolean;
    fIP, fPeerIP: string;
    fPort, fPeerPort: Integer;
    ...
  public
    constructor Create(AThread: TIdPeerThread; AAdding: Boolean); reintroduce;
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  end;

constructor TAddRemoveClientNotify.Create(AThread: TIdPeerThread; AAdding: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fAdding := AAdding;
  with AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding do
  begin
    Self.fIP := IP;
    Self.fPeerIP := PeerIP;
    Self.fPort := Port;
    Self.fPeerPort := PeerPort;
  end;
end;

procedure TAddRemoveClientNotify.DoNotify;
var
  Node: PVirtualNode;
begin
  if fAdding then
  begin
    Node := Form1.VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(nil);
    // associate fIP, fPeerIP, fPort, fPeerPort with Node as needed...
  end else
  begin
    // find the Node that is associated with fIP, fPeerIP, fPort, fPeerPort as needed...
    Node := ...;
    if Node <> nil then
      Form1.VirtualStringTree1.DeleteNode(Node);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread); 
begin 
  TAddRemoveClientNotify.Create(AThread, True).Notify;
end; 

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread); 
begin 
  TAddRemoveClientNotify.Create(AThread, False).Notify;
end;
```

Comment: looks good, haven't tried it yet cause I'm on the phone. Does Synchronize; wait until the procedure DoSynchronize is finished? Thank for your answer. I will try it as soon as I'm on the pc.

Comment: Yes. `TIdSync.Synchronize()` uses `TThread.Synchronize()` internally.

Comment: I tried your code and it works. I also made a stress test on it where clients connect and disconnect... My app crashes altough it is synchronized... I thought there would be a buffer or something?! Any idea how to improve this?

Comment: You need to provide more information about the crash. Where is it occuring exactly?  What kind of crash is it? Etc.

Comment: I'm sorry it took so long. Hope you can still help me. The Error is: [...] faulted with message: 'access violation at 0x004060e1: write of address 0x00030dd4'. Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue. [...]

Comment: That is not very helpful without knowing which exact line of code is raising that error.

Comment: this is my bugreport with madexcept: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/349314/bugreport.txt

Comment: That report suggests that the `PVirtualNode` being passed to `VirtualStringTree1.DeleteNode()`is not valid. Is your main thread code manipulating the `TVirtualStringTree` nodes while `TIdTCPServer` is running?

Comment: it does not. That's all the code I have. (from your suggestion)

Comment: there is also a problem with the disconnect... it doesn't fire until the form closes...

Comment: The OnDisconnect event handler is run in the same thread that runs the OnConnect and OnExecute events, which is not tied to the main thread. If Synchronize() is not running then the main thread is blocked doing something else and cannot process the sync request. For example, if the main thread is busy shutting down TIdTCPServer, then the OnDisconnect event cannot do anything that relies on the main thread. That is a classic deadlock that a lot of Indy newbies get into.

Comment: thank you. So what is your suggestion? I expermimented with Athread.Synchronize and my own tthread class, but still no luck. Any Idea how I can do this? I've tried everything to make this work but no luck. I started a bounty and hope you would get it.

Comment: The simpliest solution is to use `TIdNotify` instead of `TIdSync`. That will avoid any deadlock, but at the cost of the `PVirtualNode` being created and assigned asynchronously, so it might not be assigned to the `TIdPeerThread` yet when you need to use it in the `OnExecute` and `OnDisconnect` events. You should redesign the code to separate the `PVirtualNode` logic from the `TIdPeerThread` logic so they are not dependant on each other anymore. If that is not an option, then at least set a flag before deactivating the server, and then have your events check for that flag before invoking `TIdSy

Comment: sounds good. Could you give me an example please? I can also use a loop onDisconnect that checks if Athread.Data is NIL or not. If not it stays idle.

Comment: You can't block the `OnDisconnect` event at all while the server is busy being deactivated. That is the root of the deadlock. The server waits for client threads to fully terminate, but blocking the `OnDisconnect` event prevents the calling thread from terminating correctly. It doesn't matter if that blockage is from `TIdSync` or a manual loop.

Comment: I updated my answer with a `TIdNotify` example. A `PVirtualNode` is no longer stored in the `TIdPeerThread.Data` property at all.  If your `OnExecute` event needs to do anything with the client's `Node`, create another `TIdSync/TIdNotify` class that searches the `VirtualTreeNode` for the desired `Node` when needed.

Comment: thank you very much! This was worth more than 100 rep points! I appreciate your effort, time and patience.

Answer (score 2):

Since the GUI runs on the main thread you can (should) not directly access it from your own thread. You should write your own TThread class and then use Sycnhronize to handle UI calls.

Comment: `TIdTCPServer` is already running its own threads, that is why the original code was failing.  You can use Indy's `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class to sync with the main thread.