# How can I accept TCP Connections fast and synchronize my GUI?

Tags: delphi, winsock, vcl, delphi-xe4

I would like accept incoming TCP Connections as fast as I can. Yet I would also like to have an extra thread for each connection that receives the data.

Here is my TThread Class that listenes to a port:

```
procedure TListenThread.Execute;
var
  iSize     : Integer;
begin
  ConnectionAttempts := 0;
  while not (terminated) do begin
    iSize := SizeOf(cAddr);
    hClient := Accept(hServer, @cAddr, @iSize);
    if (hClient <> INVALID_SOCKET) then begin
      inc (ConnectionAttempts);
      SynchIP  := inet_ntoa(cAddr.sin_addr);
      Synchronize(WriteToLog); // Processes very fast!
      with TReceiveThread.Create(TRUE) do begin // This takes the longest...
        FreeOnTerminate   := TRUE;
        hSocket           := hClient;
        TheForm           := aForm;
        Host              := SynchIP;
        Resume;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I see that the API `CreateThread` takes quite a while to process. 
Is there a way to accept connections faster (So the `accept` has a higher priority than the ListenerThread)?

For example `accept` has the highest priority for 2 seconds (in the 2 seconds the server has accpeted about 200 connections) then create the (200) threads at once, or something like that.
Advise, Help would be appreciated.

PS.:
I do NOT want to create any Threads BEFORE a connection occurs. (This would limit the connections and would fill the memory). I would also like to stay away from Indy - I've already tested it and it seems to be the same speed.

Comment: You say you do not want to create threads beforehand, but I suggest you do just that. Create a **pool** of TReceiveThread (so you're the boss over the maximum pool size) and when you need one pick an unassigned one from the pool.

Comment: Consider connection pooling, thread pooling, or both.

Comment: If you want fast and scalable I/O on Win32 threads are pretty much exactly the wrong thing to be using.  If the thread-per-connection model really isn't enough for you, it's time to start looking at Async I/O and I/O Completion Ports.  Incidentally, recent versions of Indy support IOCP, though I believe it's still considered experimental.

Comment: @JanDoggen I would like to stay in the standard winsock TCP/IP API. How could I do a pool?

Comment: @afrazier: Indy does NOT support IOCP. That was a failed experiment that was abandoned years ago.

Comment: @BenjaminWeissL IOCP is part of the Winsock 2 API, just a different portion of it: [Windows Sockets 2.0: Write Scalable Winsock Apps Using Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Sorry about that -- I thought it was new, but I don't track Indy very closely.  I'll be more careful before making such statements in the future.

Comment: @Benjamin Plenty of examples if you Google "delphi creating a thread pool", and I suggest you also take a look at OmniThreadLibrary http://otl.17slon.com/

Comment: What have you got in TReceiveThread.Create?

Comment: @MartinJames Just a loop that receives the buffer from the client socket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with Indy?  It ships with Delphi, and its `TIdTCPServer` component does everything you are asking for.  It accepts new connections using a separate worker thread per listening port, so the main thread is not waiting.  Each accepted client runs in its own worker thread.  And client threads can optionally be pooled (despite what you think, a pool does not have to limit how many connections you can accept, just how many threads are allowed to sit idle at any given moment waiting to be reused).

If you are having speed issues with it, feel free to report it to Indy's developers.  I suspect your speed issues are likely to be related to how you are using it, rather than being issues with it itself.

Comment: I've used this tool : http://www.poisonivy-rat.com/ and used the stresser from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285593/virtualtreeview-add-roots-with-threads It accepts connections very fast and I would like to do the same. However I have no idea how to accomplish that. I've used Indy but it seems like to take forever for a TThread to create.

Comment: Yes, creating a thread is an expensive operation from the OS's perspective, and can take a moment to start running. That is what thread pooling is for. Indy has a `TIdThreadMgrPool` (Indy 9) or `TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool` (Indy 10) component for that purpose, which can be attached to `TIdTCPServer`.

Comment: Could you be so kind and provide an example?

Comment: You simply assign a `TIdThreadMgrPool` to the `TIdTCPServer.ThreadMgr` property (Indy 9), or a `TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool` to the `TIdTCPServer.Scheduler` property (Indy 10), and Indy handles the rest for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm using Indy now and I don't even need `TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool`. I've had major time issues due to execution of my app through the Delphi XE4 IDE Debugger. Everything works fine now.